# Assembly qemu-system-i386: Trying to execute code outside RAM

Tags: assembly, x86, qemu, bootloader, i386

I got this error while I was playing with qemu, `"qemu-system-i386: Trying to execute code outside RAM"`.

And on `gdb`, I got this, so it stays at the *movl* and when I execute an *stepi*, all crashes:

```
=> 0xf010002c <relocated>:      add    %al,(%eax)
relocated () at kern/entry.S:74
74              movl    $0x0,%ebp                       # nuke frame pointer
(gdb) stepi
Remote connection closed
```

This happened when I commented the line of kern/entry.S that executes:

```
movl    %eax, %cr0
```

What is the real explanation of this? Because the part of the code says a lot of things that do, but I really don't understand why, if I comment that line of code, it explodes.

```
entry:
movw    $0x1234,0x472           # warm boot


movl    $(RELOC(entry_pgdir)), %eax
movl    %eax, %cr3
# Turn on paging.
movl    %cr0, %eax
orl $(CR0_PE|CR0_PG|CR0_WP), %eax
movl    %eax, %cr0

mov $relocated, %eax
jmp *%eax
```

Comment: A guess may be that there is a problem with your page tables/directory. You probably would have to make all your code available to get a good idea of what is wrong.Do you have your code in github or some other place we can access.The problem with this question is that it isn't an [mcve]

Comment: when I do a build of it I don't get an error and it seems to run although I don't have your `.gdbinit` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That QEMU error means "your guest program just jumped off into some invalid location"; it is pretty much always the result of a buggy guest program, but it was previously something QEMU's emulation wasn't able to handle. In newer versions of QEMU (starting with 3.1, which isn't yet released) we will be able to handle execution from something other than RAM, so we'll be able to continue emulating the guest. Of course since execution from random unmapped memory makes no sense, the chances are the guest will then just sit in a loop taking exceptions or otherwise sit there apparently doing nothing.

In this particular case, you've commented out the line of code that enables the MMU, so the code immediately following it that jumps to a virtual address on the assumption that paging is enabled will crash when it tries to execute the instruction at the jump target, because without the MMU enabled there is nothing at that address.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I understand why is this error happening

Comment: Peter, do you have a link to more information about this new version 3.1 feature?

Comment: It's this patchset https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-arm/2018-07/msg00135.html which went into git master in commit 48a539df4a25b009c5a. So it's in current bleeding-edge QEMU and will be in 3.1.